# android: change variable value within CountDownTimer

Tags: android, eclipse, variables

I want to change the value of a class variable within a CountDownTimer but it doesn't work. Here is a short example which shows what I mean:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private int var;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        .
        .
        .

        var = 0;

        tmr = new CountDownTimer(t, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                var = 1;    

            }

            public void onFinish() {

            }

        }.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.d(tag, var);

    }


}
```

The output of Log.d(tag, var); is always 0 but I want to get the value set by the timer.

Comment: Please post more of your code for this class.

Comment: What is the value of the `t` variable in the constructor of `CountDownTimer`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot but that was a false alarm. The bug was somewhere else and my timer is working properly :)